# HTTP Responses - Android

Tags: android, http-headers, httpresponse

I am trying to make my application post something to my webserver (located at IP 10.0.2.2) and receive the response. I'm using a HttpHelper object to do all the server-interaction methods. At the moment my response variable is not getting anything back. Through debugging I know that the loop:

```
while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
```

is never entered, but it should be entered because it *should* receive the line 'OK' surely?

Thanks very much for your help!

The webpage code is just:

```
header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
```

The java code is:

```
        List<NameValuePair> data = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        HttpHelper httpHelper = new HttpHelper("http://10.0.2.2/", data);
        StringBuilder response = httpHelper.postData();
```

...

```
public class HttpHelper {
final HttpClient client;
final HttpPost post;
final List<NameValuePair> data;

public HttpHelper(String address, List<NameValuePair> data) {
    client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    post = new HttpPost(address);
    this.data = data;
}

private class GetResponseTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, StringBuilder> {
    protected StringBuilder doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        try {
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
            return inputStreamToString(response.getEntity().getContent());
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            Log.e("debug", e.getLocalizedMessage());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("debug", e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
        return null;
    }
}

public StringBuilder postData() {
    try {
        post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(data));
        return (new GetResponseTask().execute()).get();
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        Log.e("debug", e.getLocalizedMessage());
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        Log.e("debug", e.getLocalizedMessage());
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        Log.e("debug", e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
    return null;
}

private StringBuilder inputStreamToString(InputStream is)
        throws IOException {
    String line = "";
    StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();

    // Wrap a BufferedReader around the InputStream
    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

    // Read response until the end
    while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
        Log.v("debug", "top of readlineloop");
        total.append(line);
        Log.v("debug-readline", line);
    }
    // Return full string
    return total;
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The response entity, the one returned by getEntity(), does not include the response headers, and it looks like that's what you're interested in. To retrieve the status code, use:

```
response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()
```

The "entity" is reponse content.

EDIT: to emit content from PHP, use `echo`, `print_r()`, `var_dump()`, numerous other functions, and - most importantly - all text outside of `<?php...?>` tags.

Comment: Ah, I see thanks. Do you know the php code to set the response content?

Comment: Try `header("HTTP/1.0 123 somemessage");` as per http://php.net/manual/function.header.php

Comment: "Response content", at least in the sense of the `getContent()` method, stands for the response data, not for the status string at the end of the HTTP/ response line. Let Jonny decide what exactly does he need...

Comment: Thanks for your help everyone. Can I ask - am I going about it the right way to interface my android app with the webserver, or is there a better way than using http responses?

Comment: Under which defition of "response"? There seem to be two floating around. Typically, they use the the response data in some parse-friendly format like JSON or XML, and let the Web server generate the status line.